# Unable to reference companion object methods

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code:

```
fun process(call: () -> Int) {
}

fun aa() = 5

class A {
    companion object Factory {
        fun bb() = 6
    }
}

fun test() {
    process(::aa)   // OK
    process(::A.bb) // Overload resolution ambiguity
}
```

When I try to call `process(::A.bb)` I get the following error:

```
Error:Overload resolution ambiguity:
public constructor A() defined in ru.netimen.hitch_hikingstats.A
public companion object Factory defined in ru.netimen.hitch_hikingstats.A
```

Is there any way to reference companion object methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntactically it would be `A.Factory:bb` but it will not work. At first, `bb` is a `A.Factory.() -> Int` while `() -> Int` is required.

Secondly, callable references to object members are not supported at the moment as the Kotlin compiler says. Here's a parent task for all callable members tasks: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1183.

Comment: Thanks! But AFAIK companion object methods is Kotlin analog to Java's static methods. And we can easily reference static methods in Java. So is this going to be supported in Kotlin?

Comment: No, they are not static actually. A companion object in an instance of a corresponding companion class and its methods are instance methods. If you want to make a method of a companion object static, you need to add `@JvmStatic` annotation to this method.

Comment: What is the difference between () and A.Factory.()?

Comment: Both are function without arguments, but the latter has `this` implicit argument of type `A.Factory`.

Answer (score 7):

In Kotlin 1.4+ you can use `process(A::bb)`.

In 1.1.2+ you can use `process(A.Factory::bb)` or `process((A)::bb)`.

---

Not so long after this question was asked Kotlin 1.1 was released with support for bound callable references:

- https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/ChangeLog.md#11-m01-eap-1
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/07/first-glimpse-of-kotlin-1-1-coroutines-type-aliases-and-more/
- http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#bound-callable-references
- http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-function-and-property-references-since-11

Kotlin 1.1.2 came with a fix for [KT-15951](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15951), meaning that since then you can call `process(A.Factory::bb)`.

There is also [KT-13934](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13934) targeted for Kotlin 1.4, to support `process(A::bb)`.